# Integration over those points on an $n$-sphere with ordered nonnegative coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-geometry

I want to perform an integration over those points on an $n$-sphere, the $n+1$ coordinates of which are nonnegative and ordered (say, from largest to smallest).
(So, the points form a subregion in the first quadrant--of measure/area, obviously
$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ that of the first quadrant itself.)

What ranges of integration on the $n$ parameters/angles should be employed? (I'm thinking in terms of $n=5$, but the question seems general in nature. Also, I'm thinking in the standard terms of radius 1, centered at the origin.)

Comment: How are your angles related to your Cartesian coordinates?  There are multiple possible parametrizations for $n = 4$ and higher.

Comment: As regards the comment of Michael Seifert--I have been thinking in terms of the spherical coordinates parameterization (with $r=1$) outlined in sec. 3 of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates. I don't think I understand the point/implications of the $n \geq 4$ remark.

Comment: It's possible to denote coordinates on $S^3$ via $x_1 = \cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_2$, $x_2 = \cos \theta_1 \cos \theta_2$, $x_3 = \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_3$, $x_4 = \sin \theta_1 \cos \theta_3$.  Similar constructions are also possible for higher $n$.  However, I suspect that these coordinates won't be any better (and probably worse) for your purposes.

Comment: Also:  depending on the form of your integrand, it might be easier to write your integrals out in cartesian components and include a Dirac delta function instead:$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{x_1} \cdots \int_0^{x_{n-1}} f(x_i) \delta(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dots + x_n^2 - 1) \,dx_1 \, dx_2 \cdots dx_n.$$The limits of integration are certainly much clearer in this case, though performing the integral is probably harder.

Answer (score 0):

In my 2002 paper https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0207181 (bot. p. 2), I claim that for $n=3$, the ranges to be employed are
\begin{equation} \label{constr}
 {\pi \over 4}  \leq \theta_{1} \leq {\pi \over 2}; \quad
f(\theta_{1}) \leq \theta_{2} \leq {\pi \over 2};  \quad 
f(\theta_{2})  \leq \theta_{3} \leq {\pi \over 2};   \quad f(x) = 
{\cot^{-1} \Big( {\cos{{x}}}} \Big).
\end{equation}
This scheme obviously extends to $n \gt 3$.

However, no formal demonstration of this was presented, and, at this point in time, I do not readily see how to possibly justify this claim. (In a still prior paper 
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9904101 p. 7, the same assertion was made, but in terms of half-angles--$\frac{\theta_1}{2},\ldots$)